# IHttpActionResult vs HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to talk again about differences about `IHttpActionResult` and `HttpResponseMessage`. I know that `IHttpActionResult` is more flexible and good to use with unit testing. But currently I'm working on the project, that was migrated from WebAPI to WebAPi 2, and I want to try replace all usings of `HttpResponseMessage` with `IHttpActionResult`. 
I found in the code next lines:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
}
```

I want to clarify what is equivalent approach with `IHttpActionResult`. Is the result in code below will be equivalent to the result in the code above:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
}
```

Or should I use something else?

Comment: What you have will work just fine.

Comment: I think you can just throw an HttpResponseException:  `throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);`

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you should wrap it in a ResponseMessage - helps with [Content Negotiation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation):

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you use IHttpActionResult

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return (IHttpActionResult)InternalServerError(exception);
}
```